# ASP.NET Core Blazor templated components (WITH DICTIONARY)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

I am looking to make a template component like the one over at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0. However instead of displaying values for objects in a list I'd like to do this with a dictionary. If someone could link me to or show me how to do this I'd appreciate it. I am using .NET Core 5

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/BrianLParker/ModelToComponent

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example supplied on your link, try this:

```
<MudTableItems="@pets">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Parameter</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Value</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd>@context.Key</MudTd>
        <MudTd>@context.Value</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

@code {
    private Dictionary<String,String> pets {get; set;}= new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "token1", "asdf" },
        { "token2", "1234" }
    };
}
```